# How do I position nested comments in PHP/CSS?

Tags: php, html, css

I have comments stored in a database with the post id that the comment is on, the comments id, the comments parent id, and when it was created, the content, etc.. Now I've got a query that will select all of the comments for a particular post and loop through each one displaying it. However, how can I 'indent' the comments to show that they are a child of another comment?

My current idea (somewhat pseudo-code) was to do:

```
get comments

for each comments as comment {
    if comment has parent
        margin += 16;
        style = margin-left: margin
    else
        margin = 0

    <div class="post" style="<?php echo $style; ?>">
        ...
    </div>      
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to be working as some of the replies are not positioned correctly, or sometimes don't even position under the parent comment. Am I doing something wrong here, is there a better way to do this?

Actual Code (it's very ugly):

```
<?php
    $comments = $backend->getCommentsFromPost($post_id);

    $level = 0;
    $margin = 0;

    foreach ($comments as $comment) {
        $author = $backend->getUserById($comment['comment_author_id']);
        $author_name = $author[0]['user_name'];
        $author_id_62 = $backend->to62($author[0]['user_id']);
        $when = $backend->getTimePosted($comment['comment_created']);
        $comment_karma = 2;
        $style = "";

        if ($comment['comment_parent'] != NULL) {
            $margin = $margin + 60;
            $style = "style=\"margin-left: " . $margin . "px;\"";
        }
        else {
            $margin = 0;
        }
    ?>
        <div <?php echo $style; ?> class="post">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="comment">
                        <p class="comment-data">
                            <a href="profile.php?user=<?php echo $author_id_62;?>"><?php echo $author_name; ?></a> | <?php echo $comment_karma; ?> points | <?php echo $when; ?></p>

                        <?php echo $comment['comment_content']; ?>
                        <p class="comment-footer">
                            <a class='cbtn btn-primary' title='upvote' href='#'><span class='fa fa-arrow-up'></span></a>
                            <a class='cbtn btn-primary' title='downvote' href='#'><span class='fa fa-arrow-down'></span></a>
                            <?php
                                if ($backend->isLoggedIn()) {
                                    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
                                    $comment_id = $backend->to62($comment['comment_id']); ?>

                                    <a class='cbtn btn-primary' title='post reply' href='comment-reply.php?comment=<?php echo $comment_id; ?>'><span class='fa fa-reply'></span></a>

                            <?php
                                    if ($user_id == $author[0]['user_id'] || $backend->isUserNotPeasant($user_id)) {
                            ?>
                            <a class='cbtn btn-danger' title='delete comment' href="delete-comment.php?id=<?php echo $comment_id; ?>"><span class='fa fa-trash-o'></span></a>
                            <?php
                                    }
                                }
                            ?>
                        </p>                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

Cheers

Comment: If you've already tried this (assuming using PHP), can you post the actual code, rather than pseudo code.

Comment: Do you have the actual PHP code and SQL? It could be a sorting issue... you might need to loop through the results to build a multidimensional array that you can then looks through. All depends on your data.

Comment: I've put in the actual code, be warned it's very messy :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be simply:

```
<style>
    .post {margin-left: 0;}
    .post div {margin-left: 16px;}
</style>
<div class="post">
    POST HERE
    <div>
        reply
        <div>
            2nd reply
            <div>
                4th level
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        reply 2
    </div>
</div>
<div class="post">
    another post
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4f2wzwne/

Comment: But what if I had more than 2 levels of comments?

Comment: @DillonNyal: doesn't matter how many, I've used three levels. It works without level limitation.

Comment: Hmm, okay. I'll give it a shot!

Comment: @DillonNyal: I've just added you the second 'root' post and next, 4th level :-) Just try it, it really works. The main idea is that you make nested post, your origin idea was to have post in same hierarchy level (siblings, not parent-children).

Comment: Nice, cheers! I may have to change some styles around but hopefully it works :)

Answer (score 0):

You can prepend the comment with any number of `&emsp;` as desired. One per level seems good. Track the level depth of the comment, which you can get from your query, and translate that to number of `&emsp;` to prepend with.

Answer (score 0):

First get comments without parent, then loop in them and get child comments. That will fix your problem I think.